# React/NextJS: Dynamic Routing: TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null --> Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <div> in <div>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm have a NextJS application which I've just done two things on. 1) I've upgraded to the latest version of NextJS (9.0.1), and 2) I've copied files (package.json, pages/, components/ etc.) from my project root to a new src/app/ sub-directory in my project root.

Pages which don't use dynamic routing load perfectly fine, but there's an issue when I need to use the router object from Next. My original code (which was working fine before the above two things):

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { mockConsts } from "../../public/mockConsts";

const router = useRouter();
const userObj = mockConsts.users.filter(
  user => user.username === router.query.username
)[0];
```

This gives me the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null`.

If I wrap a try/catch around it:

```
let userObj = mockConsts.users[0];

try {
  const router = useRouter();
  userObj = mockConsts.users.filter(
    user => user.username === router.query.username
  )[0];
  console.log("QUERY", router.query);
} catch (e) {
  console.log("ERR", e);
}
```

the client and server return two different errors. The server still returns the above error (`TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null`).

The client returns (via console.log):

```
QUERY Object {  }  [username].tsx:16
Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <div> in <div>. index.js:1
QUERY Object { username: "dog" }  [username].tsx:16
```

With the try/catch I can get the code to work as intended, but only after it has displayed `mockConsts.users[0]` (The first "QUERY" in console log is blank). Obviously this isn't ideal.

EDIT:

I have rewritten the try/catch so the functionality is as I'd expect:

```
try {
    router = useRouter();
    console.log("ROUTER", router);
    userObj = mockConsts.users.filter(
      user => user.username === router!.query.username
    )[0];
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("ERR", e);
  }
```

ROUTER is logged twice:

```
ROUTER 
Object { pathname: "/user/[username]", route: "/user/[username]", query: {}, asPath: "/user/[username]", components: {…}, events: {…}, push: field(), replace: field(), reload: field(), back: field()
, … }
[username].tsx:23
ROUTER 
Object { pathname: "/user/[username]", route: "/user/[username]", query: {…}, asPath: "/user/dog", components: {…}, events: {…}, push: field(), replace: field(), reload: field(), back: field(), … }
[username].tsx:23
```

As you can see, the `query` attribute has values in it now, and the `asPath` attribute is different.